# No windows identity for DOMAIN\USER

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth, claims, security-token-service

In my SharePoint 2013 environment (1 WFE, 1 APP, NTLM, Nintex Workflow, Claims to Windows NT Token Service (c2WTS) is standard with local system) are lots of (Every seconds a few) claims authentication errors in the ULS log.

Any ideas where the problem come from? 
Any ideas how I can fix the problem?

Thank you in advance!

**ULS Log**

```
Claims Authentication Medium:

> SPSecurityContext: Could not retrieve a valid windows identity for
> username 'DOMAIN\USER' with UPN 'USER@DOMAIN.DE'. UPN is required when
> Kerberos constrained delegation is used. Exception:
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException
> 1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: WTS0003: The caller is not
> authorized to access the service. (Fault Detail is equal to An
> ExceptionDetail, likely created by
> IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: WTS0003: The caller is not
> authorized to access the service.     at
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.WindowsTokenService.CallerSecurity.CheckCaller(WindowsIdentity
> callerIdentity)      at
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.WindowsTokenService.S4UServiceContract.PerformLogon(Func
> 1 logonOperation, Int32 pid)      at SyncInvokeUpnLogon(Object ,
> Object[] , Object[] )      at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
> instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)      at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
> rpc)      at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
> rpc)      at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
> rpc)      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
> isOperationContextSet))..
```

Claims Authentication Unexpected:

> No windows identity for DOMAIN\USER.

Comment: could you please check if Claims to Windows Token Service is running on the server? from central admin > manager services on server

Comment: Pinging this as it is happening at my current client site. Speaking to several architects and a MSFT support person led me to believe it is a non issue. I just don't like seeing my logs spammed with this and would like to see if anyone has a resolution for it. Users don't seem to be impacted other than the logs getting filled up. I have tried the restarting of the service and it doesn't seem to make a difference and it is not stopped.

Comment: This is currently happening in a 2010 environment, same symptoms.  Tons of errors, no reported impact.  Bad patch?

Answer (score 2):

As i mentioned in the comment, This error is typically due to issue with `Claims to token Service.`Please make sure following things

- from central admin > manager services on server make sure CTS is running on all server in the farm.
- if not running start it.
- If running then restart them.

Comment: And what if it is already running?

Comment: Then restart them

Comment: Well, what I meant is that the service is already running and I get the error even if I restart it.

Comment: could you please check the event logs and ULS, provide us more information about the error..

Comment: SPSecurityContext: Could not retrieve a valid windows identity for username 'domain\user' with UPN 'user@domain.local'. UPN is required when Kerberos constrained delegation is used. Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: WTS0003: The caller is not authorized to access the service. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: WTS0003: The caller is not authorized to access the service.

Comment: are you using PowerPivot?

Comment: I'm not working with Excel, but SharePoint workflows (Task approvment/rejecting).